# Timer/Clock in Avalonia (very similar to wpf) MainWindowViewModel/MainWindow, how to update UI?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, avaloniaui

My Apologies if I'm just doing this whole thing wrong, I haven't touched C# in 2 decades and I'm new to MVVM. Anyhow I'm using Avalonia (which from what I understand is mostly the same as WPF but crossplatform) and I'm having some trouble with getting a clock to display in my UI. I have the following code in my MainWindow.axaml.

```
                <Border Classes="Footer" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
                    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NextDownloadCycle}"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentTime}"/>                       
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
```

In my MainWindowViewModel file I have the following code which was supposed to make this work.

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    public string CurrentTime {
        get { return _currentTime; } 
        set
        {
            _currentTime = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CurrentTime)));
            Debug.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }

    private string _nextDownloadCycle = "Next crawl session at: (in 30m)";
    public string NextDownloadCycle {
        get { return _nextDownloadCycle; }
        set 
        {
            _nextDownloadCycle = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(NextDownloadCycle)));
            Debug.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }

    private DateTime _nextCycle = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        StartClock();
    }
    private void StartClock()
    {
        new DispatcherTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), DispatcherPriority.Normal, TimerTick).Start();            
    }

    void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        if (now >= _nextCycle)
        {
            _nextCycle = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
            StartCrawling();
        }
        TimeSpan ts = _nextCycle - now;
        NextDownloadCycle = String.Format(
            "Next crawl session at: {0} (in {1}m{2}s)",
            _nextCycle.ToString("HH:mm:ss"),
            Math.Round(ts.TotalMinutes),
            ts.Seconds
        );
        CurrentTime = now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    }
```

I tried putting the PropertyChanged?.Invoke inside a `Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() => )` thinking that might somehow fix it (I'm new to this as you can probably tell) to no avail.
I am getting output in the debug console which is mostly as I expected, e.g.

```
Next crawl session at: 00:22:03 (in 60m32s)
23:22:31
```

Sometimes things go slightly awry and I get a double mention of one second followed by a 2 second gap like below, I'm guessing that's just due to rounding somehow.

```
Next crawl session at: 00:47:00 (in 60m48s)
23:47:11
Next crawl session at: 00:47:00 (in 60m48s)
23:47:12
Next crawl session at: 00:47:00 (in 60m46s)
```

Anyway, my main question is why isn't this updating the UI? What do I need to change, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you assigned DataContext? Also try using like a button that mutates the currentTime property on the ViewModel to test the binding

Comment: According to [the avalonia docs](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/data-binding/the-datacontext) it should be in program.cs although it does not appear to be. Regardless it must be sorting itself out properly somewhere as my program does load up showing "00:00:00" where I have `<TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentTime}"/>` so it seems to read the initial value just fine. But the value never gets updated.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it to work as follows. First I made a separate Clock class in the model folder that extends INotifyPropertyChanged and moved the formatting and timer logic into it.

```
public class Clock : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DispatcherTimer _disTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    public EventHandler<DateTime> OnEveryHour = (s , e) => { };

    public string CurrentTime { get; set; } = "Current Time";
    public string NextDownloadCycle { get; set; } = "Downloading in: ";

    private DateTime _nextCycle = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);

    public Clock()
    {
        _disTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        _disTimer.Tick += DispatcherTimer_Tick;
        _disTimer.Start();
    }

    private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        if (now >= _nextCycle)
        {
            _nextCycle = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
            OnEveryHour(this, now);
        }
        TimeSpan ts = _nextCycle - now;
        NextDownloadCycle = String.Format(
            "Next crawl session at {0}(in {1}m{2}s)",
            _nextCycle.ToString("HH:mm:ss"),
            Math.Round(ts.TotalMinutes) - 1,
            ts.Seconds
        );
        CurrentTime = now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CurrentTime)));
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(NextDownloadCycle)));
    }
}
```

Then in MainWindowViewModel I create my clock instance
`public Clock Clock { get; set; } = new Clock();`

And call it in the xaml as follows:

```
<Border Classes="Footer" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DataContext="{Binding Clock}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NextDownloadCycle}"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentTime}"/>                   
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Border>
```

I'll simply subscribe to `OnEveryHour` in `MainWindowViewModel` to execute `StartCrawling()` and everything should work as I want it to. (Added bonus, the code is looking [c]leaner)